# Why JupyterLab gives different output than shell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-idle, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter Lab `type('some_text')` returns `str` and in idle it returns `<class 'str'>`.

Comment: It is not the return value what is different but the textual representation used in each environment.

Answer (score 1):

IDLE displays the string representation produced by python unchanged.  This is a design decision.  Start interactive python and enter the same thing, or run `python -c "print(type(''))` at a command prompt.  Similarly,  `type(1)`, `type([])`, and `type(lambda: None)` are `<class 'int'>`, `<class 'list'>`, and `<class 'function'>` in python and hence IDLE.

Jupiter Lab does not have the same constraint, and I presume than it reduces the output to `int`, `list`, and `function` in the latter cases.  (Easy enough with re.)  I presume their thought is something like "When a user types 'type', they know they will get a class, so no reason to say so."